# Crash on [UIGestureRecognizer requiredFailureRequirementsForFailureRequirement]

Tags: ios, ios9, uigesturerecognizer

Sometimes when swiping from left edge to right I found this error appears on the call stack:

[image: Call stack]

This happens only on iOS 9 and for me it seems like system bug, but I would like to avoid it.

The complete hierarchy is pretty deep.

I am swiping the UITableView which is inside UIViewController that is on UINavigationController stack which is child of UIViewController that is contained inside UIContainerView that is inside another UIContainerView that is inside UIViewController which is pushed on the root UINavigationController stack.

On the same controller that holds the UITableView I have the UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer on the right edge.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    [otherGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:gestureRecognizer];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: So what exception message does it throw. It says that your otherGestureRecognizer object is nil or is deallocated.

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne I am logging now the otherGestureRecognizer so I wiil be able to see the its last value before the crash happens. It is so rare for crash to happen so it will take some time. Tnx for the answer.